# Placing a div outside a page container

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to get some `<div>` tags to sit outside a container on my page but without increasing the width of the page.

The content inside my website is contained within a relative div called `<div class="container">` which is, lets say 1000px wide. The container sits in the middle of the page and runs from top to bottom, and a background image is visible on either side of this container (if the user's screen size is wide enough).

Sometimes, we run promotions and display these in the background image (not very user friendly, I know). We need sections of the background image to be clickable on both the left side of the container and the right side.

The left side works fine. I added a clickable `div` inside the central container, set `position:absolute` and `left:-100px`.

However if I do the same for the right container, but change the position to `right:-100px`, the width of the whole page actually increases. This means if a user is using the website with a small screen size, they will see horizontal scroll bars.

I've made a fiddle of my problem - http://jsfiddle.net/Gsf4x/

Resize the HTML window and you'll notice how the horizontal scroll bar appears when it is resized. Is there a workaround to make the scrollbars disappear? Setting `overflow:hidden` actually hides the links. I know I could probably build something in JavaScript but I'm looking for a CSS approach.

Hope that wasn't too confusing!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

on the body.

If you set `overflow:hidden`, you wont be able to scroll down.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff2DT/)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow:hidden` on the body, like this - 
[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gsf4x/1/)

Comment: `overflow:hidden` stops the user from scrolling down. I think you meant `overflow-x:hidden`.